# change wsdl to set time pattern

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl, sap-basis

I have a asmx web service I created in c# which returns a DateTime value in one method. In WSDL, this value is assigned to a time type. 
The client is created on a SAP system and the client fails to parse this time info, getting this error:

> cx_sy_conversion_no_date_time xslt

What can be done in such a situation? The first time that comes to my mind is to change wsdl so that all time values are serialized in a way that can be parsed by the SAP client.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The error is at SAP side (`cx_sy_conversion_no_date_time`), so please add the code of the SAP Web service so that to fix the error.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 choices:

1. Change client (SAP): maybe it allows some configuration
2. Change server (.NET): send values in appropriate format, so SAP can understand them

You can extend your entity like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Entity
{
    private const string YourOwnFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "DateTime")]
    private string DateTimeString
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.ToString(YourOwnFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        set
        {
            DateTime =
                DateTime.ParseExact(value, YourOwnFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: about option 2, how can I change the server so that DateTime object can be serialized in a different pattern?

Comment: @artsince, I think, you can add in your entity with DateTime, property DateTimeString. In get accessor return formatted DateTime. In set: assign DateTime from string. Do not add `DataMember` to DateTime property.

Comment: @artsince, As I know, you can't change serialization format of datetime. It will ISO 8601.

Comment: That's very interesting. Thanks a lot.I tried your suggestion but I got an error saying string cannot be converted to time type (from System.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute(DataType=time) attribute) So I have to get rid of the time attribute, which is not very ideal.

Comment: thanks for the update. note that I use asmx. with data member and datacontract attributes, your answer seems to target wcf.

Comment: @artsince, Do the same. Send to SAP datetime like string in appropriate format.